# How to translate "rapporto bancario"?

Tags: translation, italian

In Italian, we use "rapporto bancario" as a generic word for any "banking relationship" you have with your bank, like a banking account, a mortgage, a loan, you name it.

Is "banking relationship" a correct translation?

Comment: That is certainly the term I would use. I spent five years on Wall Street at a large corporate bank a while back, and that was the term we used there. It is also the term used by my retail bank currently. Investment banks and wealth management firms tend to use other terms like "client relationship" or "advisory relationship". Anecdotally, the financial institutions I've worked with in France would occasionally use "relation bancaire"

Comment: @IsabelArcher Thank you! If you would like to add an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that, yes, "banking relationship" is the correct term, for financial institutions that accept deposits and make loans -- banks in the traditional sense of the word. During the five years I spent a while back at a large corporate bank on Wall Street, that was the term we used. It is also the term my retail bank uses currently.

Investment banks and wealth management firms tend to use other terms like "client relationship" or "advisory relationship".

Comment: This is certainly the term that banks often use in their marketing materials. It is probably used much less often by the people who are on the other side of these relationships.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @IsabelArcher says, there's another level of relationship in which one party has a duty of care, and is required, often legally, to act in the best interest of the other party. This is a ***[fiduciary relationship](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/fiduciary+duty)***.

Comment: The meaning of this term merely overlaps with the concept that the OP has in mind. Only some of the services that financial institutions provide involve their acting as fiduciaries for their clients, and there are fiduciaries who are not financial institutions.

Comment: @jsw29 - Right. My intent was to say that some banking relationships have a narrower focus. Sorry if you found it less than clear.